Problems with defining a R(c)-linear operator
My objective is to define an opeartor op such that for every rational function $f(c)$ of a fixed symbol c, $op(f(c) x)=f(c) op(x)$. What is a good way to implement this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Other possibility:
ClearAll[f, x, c, op];
op[f_?(RationalExpressionQ[#, c, NumericQ] &)*x_] := f*op[x];
op[a_ + b__] := op[a] + op[b];

op[(c^2 + 3)/(c + 1)*x^2]

(* ((3+c^2) op[x^2])/(1+c) *)

op[(c^2 + 3)/(c + 1)*x^2 + c x]

(* c op[x] + ((3 + c^2) op[x^2])/(1 + c) *)


An alternative solution using UpValues, and defining the operator as linear:
ClearAll[op, x] 
SetAttributes[op, HoldAll] 
(* Define the linearity property using UpValues *) 
op /: op[a_ + b_] := op[a] +op[b] 
(* Define the commuting property using UpValues *) 
op /: op[f_*expx_] /; FreeQ[expx, c] := f*op[expx]

Test:
op[(c^2 + 3)/(c + 1)*x^2]
(*output*)
((3+c^2)*op[x^2])/(1+c)

and for linearity:
op[(c^2 + 3)/(c + 1)*x^2+ c x] 
(* output *)
c*op[x]+((3+c^2)*op[x^2])/(1+c)


Thank you for your answer. It appears that x is declared as a special variable instead of c. Is it possible to go the other way around?

Sure!, I edited the code op /: op[f_*expx_] /; FreeQ[expx, c] := f*op[expx], so that the special variable declared is c.
